# Calculation on a hidden field

Tags: delphi

I am hiding a field so that when it is shown (on checkbox checked) it preforms a certain calculation.

```
procedure TForm1.cxCheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
C:TcxGridDBColumn;
begin
if ABSTable1.FieldByName('CENIK_IME').AsString = 'PAK' then begin
C := cxGrid2dbtableview1.GetColumnByFieldName('TT');
if Assigned(C) then C.Visible := not C.Visible;
ABSQuery2.Edit;
ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TOTAL').AsCurrency := (ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TOTAL').AsCurrency) + (ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TT').AsCurrency);
ABSQuery2.Refresh;
end;
end;
```

Problem is that every time I check or uncheck  the checkbox my TOTAL gets bigger and bigger. Any way to prevent the checkbox from summing every time it gets checked or unchecked ?

Also I have this on calculate fields of the query ;

```
procedure TForm1.ABSQuery2CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TT').Value:= (ABSQuery2.FieldByName('DAYS').AsCurrency) * 1.01 ;
end;
```

This is all done on a Temp table which is used just for the occassion. Contents get deleted all the time....

Comment: Keep a field that would indicate if you have added TT to TOTAL or  not.

Comment: What relation does hiding/unhiding the column have to do with things? (What determines whether the column is supposed to be visible/not visible?) I'm also not sure of the intent of the code in OnCalcFields - how would `Days` change just because the checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't you need to subtract ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TT').AsCurrency if the column is hidden?
And also only change Total if the TT is found?
So:

```
procedure TForm1.cxCheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  C:TcxGridDBColumn;
begin
  if ABSTable1.FieldByName('CENIK_IME').AsString = 'PAK' then begin
    C := cxGrid2dbtableview1.GetColumnByFieldName('TT');

    if Assigned(C) then 
    begin
      C.Visible := not C.Visible;

      ABSQuery2.Edit;  
      if C.Visible then
        ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TOTAL').AsCurrency := (ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TOTAL').AsCurrency) + (ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TT').AsCurrency)
      else
        ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TOTAL').AsCurrency := (ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TOTAL').AsCurrency) - (ABSQuery2.FieldByName('TT').AsCurrency);
      ABSQuery2.Post;
      ABSQuery2.Refresh;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why am I getting access violation ?

Comment: Okay, sorry, edited to include full function, hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: How can I prevent user from using the checkbox if the query is empty?

Comment: Try adding if not ABSQuery2.Active or (ABSQuery2.Bof and ABSQuery2.Eof) then Exit; to the start of the procedure